# Does GridSearchCV use predict or predict_proba, when using auc_score as score function?

Tags: scikit-learn

Does GridSearchCV use predict or predict_proba, when using auc_score as score function?

The predict function generates predicted class labels, which will always result in a triangular ROC-curve. A more curved ROC-curve is obtained using the predicted class probabilities. The latter one is, as far as I know, more accurate. If so, the area under the 'curved' ROC-curve is probably best to measure classification performance within the grid search.

Therefore I am curious if either the class labels or class probabilities are used for the grid search, when using the area under the ROC-curve as performance measure. I tried to find the answer in the code, but could not figure it out. Does anyone here know the answer?

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To use `auc_score` for grid searching you really need to use `predict_proba` or `decision_function` as you pointed out. **This is not possible in the 0.13 release.** If you do `score_func=auc_score` it will use `predict` which doesn't make any sense.

[edit]Since 0.14[/edit] *it is possible to do grid-search using auc_score*, by setting the new `scoring` parameter to `roc_auc`: `GridSearch(est, param_grid, scoring='roc_auc')`. It will do the right thing and use `predict_proba` (or `decision_function` if `predict_proba` is not available).
See the [whats new page of the current dev version](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/dev/whats_new.html).

You need to install the current master from github to get this functionality or wait until April (?) for 0.14.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will install the current master from github to get the desired functionality.

Comment: And for custom functions?, I mean I want to use a scoring function which scores with ground trouth and a predict_proba y matrix.

Comment: Somehow overlooked your question avances123. Look at the "defining your own scoring function" documentation. You can provide any callable with signature ``myfunc(estimator, X_test, y_test)``

Comment: @AndreasMueller do you have any insight on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43377189/how-to-use-log-loss-in-gridsearchcv-with-multi-class-labels-in-scikit-learn

Answer (score 1):

After performing some experiments with Sklearn SVC (which has `predict_proba` available) comparing some results with `predict_proba` and `decision_function`, it seems that `roc_auc` in `GridSearchCV` uses `decision_function` to compute AUC scores. I found a similar discussion here: [Reproducing Sklearn SVC within GridSearchCV's roc_auc scores manually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66499364)