# How to use `log_loss` in `GridSearchCV` with multi-class labels in Scikit-Learn (sklearn)?

Tags: python, optimization, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

I'm trying to use the `log_loss` argument in the `scoring` parameter of `GridSearchCV` to tune this multi-class (6 classes) classifier. I don't understand how to give it a `label` parameter.  Even if I gave it `sklearn.metrics.log_loss`, it would change for each iteration in the cross-validation so I don't understand how to give it the `labels` parameter?

I'm using `Python v3.6` and `Scikit-Learn v0.18.1`

**How can I use `GridSearchCV` with `log_loss` with multi-class model tuning?**

My class representation:

```
1    31
2    18
3    28
4    19
5    17
6    22
Name: encoding, dtype: int64
```

My code:

```
param_test = {"criterion": ["friedman_mse", "mse", "mae"]}
gsearch_gbc = GridSearchCV(estimator = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=10), 
                        param_grid = param_test, scoring="log_loss", n_jobs=1, iid=False, cv=cv_indices)
gsearch_gbc.fit(df_attr, Se_targets)
```

Here's the tail end of the error and the full one is here https://pastebin.com/1CshpEBN:

```
ValueError: y_true contains only one label (1). Please provide the true labels explicitly through the labels argument.
```

**UPDATE:** 
Just use this to make the scorer based on based on @Grr

```
log_loss_build = lambda y: metrics.make_scorer(metrics.log_loss, greater_is_better=False, needs_proba=True, labels=sorted(np.unique(y)))
```

Comment: Print your `Se_targets` here. And also have a look at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#multilabel-ranking-metrics

Comment: @O.rka : labels=sorted(np.unique(y)) . Here y contains   labels for entries in train set, right? Or does it contain labels for all the entries in the dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my assumption is that somehow your data split has only one class label in y_true. while this seems unlikely based on the distribution you posted, i guess it is possible. While i havent run into this before it seems that in `[sklearn.metrics.log_loss`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html) the label argument is expected if the labels are all the same. The wording of this section of the documentation also makes it seem as if the method imputes a binary classification if `labels` is not passed.

Now as you correctly assume you should pass `log_loss` as `scorer=sklearn.metrics.log_loss(labels=your_labels)`

Comment: would my labels be the same as the "y_true"?

Comment: I believe you would pass your list of classes, i.e. `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`. It looks like the `labels=` kwarg uses the `LabelBinarizer` to create the label classes and then binarize the y_true values. Check it out in the source [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/classification.py#L1557-L1677)

Comment: `TypeError: log_loss() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y_true' and 'y_pred'` The method takes 2  default arguments that will change during cross-validation.

Comment: you may have to use the [`make_scorer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply specify "neg_log_loss_scorer" (or "log_loss_scorer") in older versions which will use the negative log loss.